# SQL Transaction Replication prevents procedure with distinct on varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

When I'm adding one procedure article to the Publication the I get this error:

The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

the proc is a simple

```
select distinct field1, field2, fieldn from tablex where id = @param1
```

The database is on compatibility level 80.

The source server is SQL 2008 R2.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Gabriel Guimarães

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, due to the sql 2000 compatibility (80) of the database, I've set an option on the replication to:
Convert MAX data types to NText and IMAGE.

so by doing a convert to varchar(max) it was solved.